# Print text above the errorbar cap with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently working on a somewhat simple bar graph, but I want to add the mean and standard deviation text above the corresponding bars. The problem is that the bars in my graph aren't remotely the same size, so I can't use the rectangle object to define height. Doing so results in an image like this:
[image]

Of course, this is completely unacceptable, so I've been trying to find a way to do the same thing, except with the caps of the error bars.

My current code is this:

```
bar = plt.bar(names, means, yerr=sterr, capsize=5, color=colors)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,0.35,step=0.05))
plt.ylabel('Percentage of appearance')
plt.xlabel('Pot in question')   

# Add numbers in plot
for i, rectangle in enumerate(bar):
    height = rectangle.get_height()
    plt.text(rectangle.get_x() + rectangle.get_width()/2, height+0.01,
             '$\mu=$%s \n $\sigma=$%s' % (str(round(height,3))[1:], str(round(sterr[i],3))[1:]),
             ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

The new code would replace the rectangles in the for loop with the caps of the error bar plot.

Moving on to my attempt, I opened up the BarContainer object object and found this:

```
{'patches': [<matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x0000020C44BB8CF8>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x0000020C44BB8FD0>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x0000020C44BC6390>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x0000020C44BC66D8>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x0000020C44BC6A20>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x0000020C44BC6DA0>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x0000020C44BD4160>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x0000020C44BD44E0>], 'errorbar': <ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists>, 'eventson': False, '_oid': 0, '_propobservers': {}, '_remove_method': <function _AxesBase.add_container.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000020C3F71EF28>, '_label': '_container1'}
```

This has an ErrorbarContainer object, so I tried opening that up which showed this:

```
{'lines': (None, (<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000020C44BD4DA0>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000020C44BD4EB8>), (<matplotlib.collections.LineCollection object at 0x0000020C44BD4860>,)), 'has_xerr': False, 'has_yerr': True, 'eventson': False, '_oid': 0, '_propobservers': {}, '_remove_method': None, '_label': '_nolegend_'}
```

But neither of these gave me any ideas on how I could proceed.

Comment: Can you share the data so that we can reproduce and give yo u some concrete solution? I would first try to use corresponding `1.1*(means + yerr)` as the `y` coordinate for a given text. That way you would put the text above the top error bar

Comment: `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection.segments` might have the actual line parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scale the position of the text by the height of the error bars?

```
names = ['bob', 'sharon', 'han solo', 'the dude']
means = [14, 13, 1, 22]
sterr = [1, 3, 5, 1.4]
colors = ['red','green','blue','pink']

bar = plt.bar(names, means, yerr=sterr, capsize=5, color=colors)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,0.35,step=0.05))
plt.ylabel('Percentage of appearance')
plt.xlabel('Pot in question')   

# Add numbers in plot
for i, rectangle in enumerate(bar):
    height = rectangle.get_height()
    plt.text(rectangle.get_x() + rectangle.get_width()/2, height+sterr[i] + 0.3,
         '$\mu=$%s \n $\sigma=$%s' % (str(round(height,3))[1:],     str(round(sterr[i],3))[1:]),
             ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

[image]

It's rough but you get the picture. This plot shows a solution to your problem and generates a few more with the made up data, I reckon.

Comment: This is actually perfect. I hate how simple the solution to this is... xD